# What is the opposite of retired in computing?

Tags: computing

In some companies there are some hardware, like PCs, that are out of use (stored in the warehouse), and we say they are "retired".
What is the opposite? How can we name the PCs in use, and what is the verb to refer to the action to make some PC usable.
In Spanish is Alta/Baja, and the verb is "Dar de alta / Dar de baja".
Thanks.

Comment: 'Active' ? 'Current' ?

Comment: "In service", but there are shades of gray here for what the machine is used for.

Comment: When you say "to make some PC useable" do you mean _to change an old, faulty or obsolete PC so that it can be used_; or do you mean _to  remove it from the store and bring it into use without further work_? "To make something usable" means the first in normal speech but the context of your question makes me think that you mean the second.

Comment: @BoldBen, you are right, I meant the second example.

Comment: In that case you should refer to them as computers which have been "returned to use" rather than "made usable" as no repair or refurbishment has been carried out. "Made usable" implies that the computers were actually unusable until some repair, refurbishment or upgrade has been carried out.

Answer (score 2):

The opposite (as you have already said) is **in use**. Though you could also use **active**.

> **active** adjective
>   ac·tive | \ˈak-tiv  \
>   ...
>   9 : engaged in full-time service especially in the armed forces
>   active duty
>   10 : marked by present operation, transaction, movement, or use
>   an active account
>   ...
>   <sup>https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/active</sup>

The act of returning retired equipment to use is usually **restoring**, though sometimes also **reviving** or **resurrecting**, depending on the perception of just how retired something was.

> **restore** verb
>   re·store | \ri-ˈstȯr  \
>   restored; restoring
>   *transitive verb*
>
> 1 : GIVE BACK, RETURN
>   2 : to put or bring back into existence or use
>   3 : to bring back to or put back into a former or original state : RENEW
>   4 : to put again in possession of something
>   <sup>https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/restore</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The most common word that refers to used computers that have been certified as functional and resold, is [**refurbished**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/refurbished):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> : to brighten or freshen up : RENOVATE

An example of this use is at the Dell website [www.dellrefurbished.ca](https://www.dellrefurbished.ca/):

> Off Lease Dell Refurbished Computers and Accessories Direct from Dell